# Where are system images located?

Tags: 11.04, unity, themes, system

I understand where theme images are located, but those are only controls like minimize and maximize and close. Where are ALL of the images in Ubuntu located? Pretty much all control images. I know they are "controlled" by engines but where are the engines located and where are their images?

Also, where are the Unity images located? I want to change up the look because the transparent gray isn't working for me. Thankyou for any and all help!

Answer (score 1):

Do you search the location on disk, or applications to change them?

```
 locate icons | egrep "icons$"
```

will find a lot of directories with icons.

Comment: On disk. Do you specifically know where the background images/icons are for the top panel background and Unity in general?

Comment: Nvm I found them, but if I want to interchange the image do I just run nautilus as root? It seems when I did that I could "change" the file or image or whatever but I would go back to it and it reverted back to the old one.

Comment: You can run nautilus as root if you need to. But beware that these images are under package management. That means that if an update comes along to the package that's responsible for whatever images you change, it'll overwrite your changes. It's better to read up on how to make your own theme.